# how to evaluate a nested expression with right_pad in spring mvc ftl

Tags: spring-mvc, el

I have a below expression that our ftl templat has and want to evaluate

```
${employee.Number?right_pad(SPACE)}
```

Sometime it is coming as `null` so i want to put empty string if it is coming as `null` . So i tried putting the below statements in place of `employee.Number` but it didn't work. It gives syntax error.

```
${${(employee.Number)!""}?right_pad(SPACE)}


${${employee.Number?has_content?then(employee.Number, "")}?right_pad(SPACE)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using parenthesis has fixed the syntax error. Now I able to render the pdf.

${((employee.Number)!"")?right_pad(SPACE)}